# Running phylocom in R

Tags: r, executable, phylogeny

I'm trying to perform a bladj in R language using the phylocom interface but, when I run (as in the package's example) the following commands

```
path <- "~/Mac/Courses_Rice/EcolJClub563/Fall10/phylometa_stuff/R_tutorial/bladjing/"
(tree2 <- rbladj(tree, path = path, fixroot = TRUE))
```

I only get the following message:
Error: phylocom not found - make sure your path is correct

I also downloaded the software into my computer and substitute the path with the path to the location of the executable, but I only get the same error.

I am running on Windows 10 (64 bits)

Can anybody tell me PLEASE how to fix it?

Best!

Paolo

Comment: Welcome to SO! The path is unlikely to function locally, so you might need to update it with the path to the necessary files on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer @nya. I did, I also downloaded the executable to my own machine, and did not work either.